# Animation doesn't start at the expected position center instead of leading top

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I am trying to implement an animation to symbolize the “swipe down”. It's basically a circle scaling and moving down. I've done it but it only works with a tap gesture to start the animation and I want to run the animation right after the content appear using `onAppear`.

So, this works fine (starts in the middle):

```swift
Circle()
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
    .shadow(radius: 10)
    .offset(y: self.animated ? 350 : 0)
    .scaleEffect(self.animated ? 0.33 : 1)
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).delay(0.8).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
            self.animated.toggle()
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work:

```swift
Circle()
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
    .shadow(radius: 10)
    .offset(y: self.animated ? 350 : 0)
    .scaleEffect(self.animated ? 0.33 : 1)
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).delay(0.8).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
            self.animated.toggle()
        }
    }
```

The animation start from the leading top but I thought using `onAppear` that every element was already in place.

[image: Circle animation]

Any clue why the animation doesn't start where it should start?

#### UPDATE

Full content view code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var animated = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                    .offset(y: self.animated ? 350 : 0)
                    .scaleEffect(self.animated ? 0.33 : 1)
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).delay(0.8).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                            self.animated.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out what was the issue. For some reason `NavigationView` was messing with the initial layout of the `Circle`. I just removed it and things started working as expected.

[image: Circle animation as expected]

Final code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var animated = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .offset(y: self.animated ? 350 : 0)
                .scaleEffect(self.animated ? 0.33 : 1)
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).delay(0.8).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                        self.animated.toggle()
                    }
                }
        }
    }

}
```